# Converting user input to time and substracting it from main time

Tags: python, time, kivy

I am doing some project for myself and i am stuck with an assignment.

```
I have strict time that's 30min
I have a user that gives an input like: 24008
```

I need to convert an user input to time(2min:40sec:08milisec) and substract it from main time.
I tried time.strftime('%M:%S:%f', 1800) to show main Time (30min) like 30:00:00 but i don't seem to get the datetime or time imports and how do they work. Same with user input.

Can anyone with a kind heart would guide me to a right path on how to get this logic done and by what function?

I can't share a code because i don't have any working logic for this one.

Comment: Will the format of the user input always be the same?

Comment: Yes.
I am trying to make something like this, but in kivy:https://wumpa.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [datetime.time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects) object would probably be the best data structure to use for this

Your initial value of 30 minutes would be defined like this

```
import datetime
strict_time = datetime.time(minutes=30)
```

If the user input you gave as an example will always be the input format then it becomes a little hard to parse as python's datetime module's strptime behaviour does not handle 2-digit millisecond inputs and 1 digit minute inputs. If the input format is *exactly* the same (5 digits with 1 minute digit, 2 second digits and 2 millisecond digits) then the following would work

```
user_input = '24008'
input_time = datetime.timedelta(
    minutes=int(user_input[0]),
    seconds=int(user_input[1:2]),
    microseconds=int(user_input[3:4])
)

new_time = strict_time - input_time
```

Comment: when i try to run in IDE last instruction, it gives me this:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

Then how to substract both times?

Comment: Ah, sorry you should use a datetime.timedelta object for the input. Updated the answer

Comment: Now something different shows up: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Also, another question: When i make user_input into input time it gives me 0:02:04 not 0:02:40:08. Any idea how to go arround it?